# Is there a "best method" for launching services that need root access?

Tags: redhawksdr

We have several hardware devices that require the use of raw sockets to communicate with them. In order to do this we are running a UDP proxy to send the data to the device. The UDP proxy requires root access in order to run.

What are some options for launching this service using REDHAWK? It should not be launched at startup and needs to be launched on demand ideally as part of a waveform.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Evans put a lot of thought into this when he developed the [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) FTP server. In particular, his [design notes](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/DESIGN.txt) deserve careful study.

In a nutshell, the software starts up with root permissions, but immediately creates an unprivileged child process that handles all the interactions with the outside world. The child process sanitizes incoming requests, and passes them on to the parent process. The parent process also distrusts everything sent to it by the child process, and only takes the requested action when it is sure that there is nothing untoward going on.

Since an outside user can only interact with the child process, it is much harder to compromise the privileged status of the parent process.

Comment: I am not going to down-vote but this question has nothing to do about design and everything to do about starting a service via the REDHAWK framework.

Comment: @SirBedevere I had assumed you were planning to use some sort of audio-to-binary conversion tool to translate external radio signals into software instructions. If so, it would definitely be worth protecting your application with measures like these. The protocol used to communicate with your software is irrelevant in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There's really two parts to your question, the generic Linux one has a few possible answers:

1. Does your UDP proxy really require root? If you can use ports above 1024 then your process won't require privileged access.
2. Alternatively you can do fancy things like port forwarding and share responsibilities between privileged and unprivileged processes through IPC mechanisms.

The second part of your question I think is the one you really care about and is harder to google, what does this look like in Redhawk? Redhawk processes typically executes in user land, though the underlying transport omniORB runs as a Linux service and requires root access to configure/start/stop. I have not seen an example of someone executing a single Redhawk process with root from a general install that isn't privileged so I'm not sure how that would work. And I don't recommend installing Redhawk as a whole with root privilege as that's a blatant security risk and totally unnecessary. In any case, the way you'd integrate your proxy service is roughly as follows:

3. If you have source code to your proxy, you can port that into a Redhawk Device block which roughly represents an application level device driver for your attached peripherals (SDRs generally). Each Redhawk Device has a tx/rx thread and several standard functions/APIs that you can use to control it's state. This would be the most natural way to import.
4. If you don't have source code, or the proxy already has it's own API, you can #include that in a Redhawk Device and just write the glue code to translate into the Redhawk APIs. This is similar to what the USRP_UHD Device does, since it basically uses the UHD library as the 'child' interface. This also may help if you really have to have privileged access for the proxy since you could keep it as a privileged service and just interface to the user land Redhawk Device.
5. Once you have a Redhawk Device, you would add it to a Redhawk Node that can be launched either at startup or on command through a python or bash script. The cmd `nodeBooter -d $SDRROOT/dev/nodes/DeviceManager/DeviceManager.dcd.xml` or something similar would get you there. I know you said it should **not** be started on boot, but the general practice for Devices (drivers) is that they are always available for asynchronous connections. Anyway, once you have the node running, you could launch waveforms against that node/device either through a python script or the IDE. Launching waveforms against devices consists of three things: meeting waveform dependencies, setting up (Redhawk) port connections, and allocating RF tuners (starting the data flow). I'll admit that won't seem like the most straight forward way, but there are system level reasons why it's done that way.
6. Alternatively, depending on your end goal, you can do #2 or #3 above in a Redhawk **Component** instead of a Device. There's not much technical difference except in the convention and how people will expect to use your hardware/system/apps. As a Component you can directly add it to your Waveform (much like GNU Radio) so it's all one entity. This is usually easier for people to figure out and requires less steps to get working, but it could present issues if you work with other people or are building a larger system. Building hardware interfaces into Devices and running them in Nodes provides a decoupling from the Waveforms (applications) so that you don't have to switch out Components everytime you use a different RF frontend.

Anyway, that should get you thinking. I'd recommend reading the Redhawk manual, though it's pretty large at this point. Search for python examples they're the easiest way to see how you can manipulate the framework. To explore the python functions available:

```
$ python
>>> from ossie.utils import redhawk
>>> domain = redhawk.attach('REDHAWK_DEV')
>>> dir(domain)
```